# ssh connections to Ubuntu are intermittent

Tags: networking, ssh, openssh, sshd

I'm trying to use ssh to connect from a Mac to Ubuntu 12.04. I get "Connection reset by peer." Try again and I get "port 22: Connection refused." Keep trying and I get password prompt. Enter password and login successfully. Do a couple commands and then "Write failed: Broken pipe" and the connection is dropped.

The network is wired Ethernet. Both Ubuntu server and Mac client on same subnet plugged into the same switch. Other networking from both seems to be working fine, i.e. I can use web browser.

I have done `apt-get install openssh-server`

I logged into the console and checked that sshd is running.

```
ps -ef | grep sshd
root 1003 1 0 Nov29 ? 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

I have run 
`ufw allow ssh`

Then on the Mac try this over and over:

```
Kens-MacBook-Pro-44% ssh 10.1.10.197
ssh: connect to host 10.1.10.197 port 22: Connection reset by peer
Kens-MacBook-Pro-44% ssh 10.1.10.197
ssh: connect to host 10.1.10.197 port 22: Connection refused
Kens-MacBook-Pro-44% ssh 10.1.10.197
ssh: connect to host 10.1.10.197 port 22: Connection refused
Kens-MacBook-Pro-44% ssh 10.1.10.197
garges@10.1.10.197's password: `
```

All of a sudden it works. Put in the password and

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-72-generic-pae i686)...
```

So I can do some stuff like show you the log:

```
garges@oxfordhouse:~$ cd /var/log
garges@oxfordhouse:/var/log$ tail auth.log
Nov 30 00:06:00 oxfordhouse sshd[3392]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user garges
Nov 30 00:08:49 oxfordhouse sshd[3647]: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
Nov 30 00:08:49 oxfordhouse sshd[3647]: Connection from 10.1.10.14 port 55453
Nov 30 00:08:49 oxfordhouse sshd[3647]: Failed publickey for garges from 10.1.10.14 port 55453 ssh2
Nov 30 00:08:49 oxfordhouse sshd[3647]: Failed publickey for garges from 10.1.10.14 port 55453 ssh2
Nov 30 00:08:57 oxfordhouse sshd[3647]: Accepted password for garges from 10.1.10.14 port 55453 ssh2
Nov 30 00:08:57 oxfordhouse sshd[3647]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user garges by (uid=0)
Nov 30 00:08:57 oxfordhouse sshd[3647]: User child is on pid 3773
Nov 30 00:09:01 oxfordhouse CRON[3876]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 30 00:09:02 oxfordhouse CRON[3876]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root`
```

And show you my config file:

```
garges@oxfordhouse:/var/log$ cd /etc/ssh
garges@oxfordhouse:/etc/ssh$ cat sshd_config
# Package generated configuration file

# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details`

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel VERBOSE

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

A couple other meaningless ls commands and then bang, connection gets closed:

```
garges@oxfordhouse:/etc/ssh$ ls
moduli       sshd_config.bak       ssh_host_ecdsa_key      ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
ssh_config   ssh_host_dsa_key      ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub  ssh_import_id
sshd_config  ssh_host_dsa_key.pub  ssh_host_rsa_key
garges@oxfordhouse:/etc/ssh$  Write failed: Broken pipe
Kens-MacBook-Pro-44%
```

This whole scenario is very repeatable. Happens even after a reboot of both Mac and Ubuntu. Other network connections on both Mac and Ubuntu work fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's really strange. Seems an underlying network problem; are you sure there are no duplicated IP around? Try to see with `ifconfig -a` if you have a lot of dropped/error packets.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange indeed. You could try several alternatives:

- `sudo ping -f 10.1.10.197` to send a lot of ICMPs packages. This write a dot while sending a packet and remove it when receive a response (pong). If your screen start writing a lots of dots is because packets get dropped somewhere in the middle.
- `mtr 10.1.10.197` is traceroute with steroids.
- `arp-scan -t 200 -l -I eth0` to find if someone also have the same IP (as Rmano says). You could try static IP address to avoid this one.
- Set the *keep alive* preference on ssh client (adding the amount of seconds before the server with send the no-op code):
- Globally on `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`adding: `ServerAliveInterval 60`
- or to current user by adding in `~/.ssh/config`:

> Host *
>
> ServerAliveInterval 60

Also, take a look to [mosh](https://mosh.org/) - *mobile shell with roaming and intelligent local echo*.